# How can i make a node.js server to listen to my ip on my lan instead of localhost

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, lan

I have a website built on top of expressjs and node.js which is running fine on my localhost. How can i make it to run on my ip(192.168.69.100) instead of localhost so that other users on my LAN can access it.?

Thanks in advance. :)

A snippet of my code

```
app.listen(port,function (err) {
if(err)
{
    console.log(err);
}

console.log('Running on ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default node will run on every IP address exposed by the host on which it runs. You don't need to do anything special. You already knew the server runs on a particular port. You can prove this, by using that IP address on a browser on that machine:

```
http://192.168.69.100:port
```

If that didn't work, you might have your IP address wrong.

Comment: You are right.Didnt know that. Thanks.One more- Any simple method to find the list of current users which are connected to my server(192.168.69.100) on network? may be there IP addresses on console?

Answer (score 0):

Might be good to give the device running node a fixed-ip if you're using DHCP; at some point your IP-address might change and the server is not accessible anymore. Alternatively you can use your hostname after some additional work.

Comment: IP is static. Thanks .:)