# How can I host a node.js website on the my local network?

Tags: node.js, hosting, lan

I have created a web app with node.js but i want to test it on my phone and other devices.

Something like [prepros](http://prepros.io) works for static sites as you put in your ip address on any device on the same wifi network and it will display the page.

How wold i set up my node app so it works on the network not just on localhost?

Comment: Already has an answer here: [How can i make a node.js server to listen to my ip on my lan instead of localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35669861/3507137)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ip `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`, it will make the server listens all interface.

You may need to use `sudo` to listen that IP.